# Multivariate Normal Bayesian Updating with Conjugate Priors but Non-Standard Likelihood

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

I am trying to solve for the posterior of two parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. I have priors $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ respectively, where $\mathrm{Corr}[\theta_1,\theta_2] = \rho$ (i.e., $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ is a bivariate normal with correlation $\rho$). I also observe data
$$
y_1 \mid \theta_1,\nu_1^{2} \sim N(\theta_1, \nu_1^{2}) \\
y_2 \mid \theta_2,\nu_2^{2} \sim N(\theta_2, \nu_2^{2})
$$
where $\nu_1^{2}$, $\nu_2^{2}$, and $\rho$ are all known. Solving for posteriors is straightforward in this context--I can just plugin the closed-form expression for a multivariate normal with conjugate priors with known variance-covariance matrix (follow page 71 from [http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/)).

My trouble comes from another fact. I also observe
$$
y_3 \mid \theta_1, \theta_2, \nu^{2}_3 \sim N(a_0 + a_1\theta_1 + a_2 \theta_2, \nu^{2}_3)
$$
where $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, and $\nu_3^{2}$ are known. What is the posterior after seeing a draw $y_3$?

I **think** that I can just relabel $a_0 + a_1\theta_1 + a_2 \theta_2$ as $\theta_3$ and treat it as a third parameter. I could solve for the joint prior of $(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3)$ and proceed in the standard fashion. After doing this, I would expect that the posterior for $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ would be the same as the conditional posterior $(\theta_1, \theta_2)\mid \theta_3$. Is that right?

Is any of this correct, or am I way off?

---

EDIT:

I tried just including $\theta_3$ and proceeding in the standard fashion, but I ran into some issues when I simulated it. Specifically, the posteriors for $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $\theta_3$ do not always agree. In particular, I would expect to have posteriors $\theta_{N3} = a_0 + a_1\theta_{N1} + a_2\theta_{N2}$. If this
procedure used all of the available information (i.e., $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2$), this equality should
always hold. But it does not.

Below is my simulation code in Julia that demonstrates this issue. It is especially apparent if you set $\nu_1^2$ or $\nu_2^2$ to be large (e.g., 100).

````
using Statistics
using Distributions

# Generate θ's
μ1 = 0
μ2 = 0
σ2_1 = .5
σ2_2 = 1
ρ12  = .6
θ1, θ2 = rand(MvNormal([μ1, μ2], [σ2_1 ρ12; ρ12 σ2_2]))
a0, a1, a2 = 1, 2, 1
θ3 = a0 + a1*θ1 + a2*θ2

# Construct prior for θ3
cov12 = ρ12 * (sqrt(σ2_1)*sqrt(σ2_2))
σ2_3 = a1^2*σ2_1 + a2^2*σ2_2 + a1*a2*2*cov12
ρ13 = (a1*σ2_1 + a2*cov12)/(sqrt(σ2_1)*sqrt(σ2_3))
ρ23 = (a1*cov12 + a2*σ2_2)/(sqrt(σ2_2)*sqrt(σ2_3))
# Prior variance covariance matrix
Λ  = [σ2_1 ρ12 ρ13;
      ρ12 σ2_2 ρ23;
      ρ13 ρ23 σ2_3]
# Prior means vector
μ = [μ1, μ2, a0 + a1*μ1 + a2*μ2]

# Simulate N draws of y data.
N = 10_000
ν2_1 = 2
ν2_2 = 3
ν2_3 = 1
Σ = [ν2_1 0 0;
     0 ν2_2 0;
     0 0 ν2_3]
y = rand(MvNormal([θ1, θ2, θ3], Σ), N)
y1, y2, y3 = y[1, :], y[2, :], y[3, :]

# Get posterior
θN = (Λ^(-1) + N*Σ^(-1))^(-1)*(Λ^(-1)*μ + N*Σ^(-1)*[mean(y1), mean(y2), mean(y3)])
ΛN = (Λ^(-1) + N*Σ^(-1))^(-1)
# This is often false
isapprox(θN[3], a0 + a1*θN[1] + a2*θN[2]; atol = .01)
```
````

Comment: This a standard conjugate setting as the triplet of observations remains normal.

Comment: I think treating $\theta_3$ in this way leaves some information on the table since it does not use the fact that $\theta_3$ is a constant given $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. But I could be wrong. I edited the question to include simulation code that illustrates my concern.

Comment: I see no reason to introduce $\theta_3$ on top of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, especially since the mean of $y_3$ is a linear transform of these. Write down the joint log-likelihood of the triplet and you'll find a second degree polynomial in $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$.